# Isolated Storage Exception in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, exception, isolatedstorage

I've isolated storage in my silverlight application to store some information for specific users.

On every login, I check storage space by using

`IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()`

After that I store some information in local variable and then clear all storage and get it again by using these lines

```
IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().Remove();
IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
```

Sometimes I get error on **IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().** Error detail is

```
System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException was caught
Message=Initialization failed.
StackTrace:
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.FetchOrCreateStore(String groupName, String storeName, IsolatedStorageFile isf)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStore(String group, String id)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
```

Error occurs randomly but when it happens,I lost my all data in storage. I don't know the reason of this error and didn't find any helpful article. I also found many related questions but my problem is still there.

**Edit:** I just got to know the reason of this behavior and that is [According to this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/7ay840d1%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

`If any of the directories or files in the store are in use, the removal attempt for the store fails. Any subsequent attempts to modify the store throw an IsolatedStorageException exception. In this case, you must ensure that the files or directories are explicitly deleted.`

But I did find any method to explicitly delete whole store. Can anyone suggest me any solution?